# Should unit test member variables be private or public?

Tags: java, junit

Consider the following (pseudo-ish) unit test class.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest {

    private static final int MY_CONSTANT = 7;

    private Object object;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        object = new Object();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertEquals(MY_CONSTANT, object.property1);
    }

}
```

What I'd like to know is whether there is any best practice for which access modifier to use for the members `MY_CONSTANT` and `object`. In a non-test class you would obviously expose as little of the class internals as possible and use the `private` modifier. However, in a unit test that doesn't seem to matter much, so we could also make the members `public`.

So is it really arbitrary which access modifier I use or am I missing something?

Comment: But why make them public?

Comment: If there's no reason to make them public, keep them private.

Comment: In a non-test class constants are usually `public`, used as default values. In a test class you probably won't reference them outside so they can be `private`.

Comment: It reduces the amount of code to not include the `private` keyword. That's why I like to do it. Also its tests so I do not think the private is required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a matter of taste and project standards, but I usually go for the rule of thumb that says that if there's no **good** reason to have it `public` (or `protected`, for that matter), it should be `private`. This prevents other tests from mistakenly using these member variables (again, unless there's a **good** reason) and mainly helps give the project a streamlined look - production code and testing code follow the same standards.

EDIT:
As mentioned by @dkatzel in the comments (thanks!) some fields annotated by JUnit's (or other similar frameworks) annotations must have a specific set of modifiers. E.g., fields annotated with `@Rule` must be `public` and fields annotated with `@ClassRule` must be `public static` (at least from JUnit 4.11. Earlier 4.x versions are a bit more lax about the `static` modifier).

Comment: The only caveat I would add is there are some things such as JUnit Rules that must be on public fields.  But I guess that is covered by the "good reasons"

Comment: @dkatzel good point. Although, indeed, that's a type of a "good reason" :-) I'll edit my answer to include this caveat.